# Set a bash variable each time the directory changes

Tags: bash, path, prompt

I would like a variable available my bash shell similar to `pwd` but equal to a section of the current working directory, rather than the whole path.

i.e.,

```
$PWD=/a/b/c/d/e/f  
$PATH_SECT=c/d/e
```

I have a prompt that displays this path already, but I would like to update a variable in the environment to this value each time I change directory.

How could I do this?

Comment: do you need this environment variable only for your bash prompt or to use it in your commands also?

Comment: I want to be able to run commands in the shell using the variable.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `promptcmd` function. From `man bash` we learn that this function is executed just prior to showing the prompt. It's empty by default (or rather, not defined).

A simple example:

```
promptcmd(){
    local p=$(pwd)
    PATH_SECT=${p/\/a\/b\/}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what, if anything, changed, but `promptcmd` is not found at all in the bash man page, and it doesn't work for me.  `PROMPT_COMMAND` is the closest thing I could find, which is a variable that's evaluated before each prompt is displayed.  This can be combined with a function that modifies a variable or `PS1` so that the prompt is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `alias` and a function in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias cd="supercd"  # call the function
function supercd(){
  builtin cd "$@"   # original cd
  PATH_SECT=$(pwd)  # or whatever
}
```